# How do construct a url that has an ampersand in one of the query parameter values?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an input, `comment` that contains "&". How can I use the jQuery ajax get method with this value?

For example:

```
index.php?comment=i&you
```

where the actual value of the comment field is `i&you` would be wrong to use as the url.

Answer (score 3):

Pass parameters as a map in the 2nd argument (data).

```
$.get("index.php", {"comment": "i&you"});
```

jQuery will take care about URL encoding.

#### See also:

- [`jQuery.get()` API doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

---

Or if those values *actually* come from a form, just do

```
$.get("index.php", $("#formid").serialize());
```

#### See also:

- [`jQuery.serialize()` API doc](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `escape()` function:

```
var comment = 'i&you';
var url = 'index.php?comment=' + escape(comment); #=> index.php?comment=i%26you
```

**Edit:**

Missed the jQuery part, sorry.  In your `$.ajax()` call, do:

```
$.ajax('index.php', {
    'data': { 'comment': 'i&you', ... }
    ...
});
```

By passing an object (or a string) to the `data` property in the `options` argument ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)), you can ensure that your data is properly escaped without having to explicitly do it yourself.

Comment: Not really scalable.  Much better to let jQuery do the encoding and build the full url.

Comment: Whoops, missed the jQuery part.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) method to add data to your request.  Serialize will properly encode your data for you.

```
$.get( 'index.php', $('form').serialize(), function(result) {
   // do something with result
});
```

Or if just sending one input back:

```
$.get( 'index.php', $('input#comment').serialize(), function(result) {
   // do something with result
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you mean, but to run an AJAX call with jQuery you would do the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "index.php?comment=i&you",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    // Whatever you need to do goes in this function
  }
});
```

Comment: This won't encode the ampersand, you'll end up with `i` as the value for comment and another parameter `you` with an empty value.